# Need some help for this JavaScript code for DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, date, datepicker

here is my code :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#startDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {


      function isDonePressed() {
        return ($('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1);
      }

      if (isDonePressed()) {
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1)).trigger('change');

        $('.date-picker').focusout()
      }
    },
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {

      inst.dpDiv.addClass('month_year_datepicker')

      if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
        year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
        month = datestr.substring(0, 2);
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month - 1, 1));
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month - 1, 1));
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="startDate" />
```

The problem is I don't know why the date changes to first day of the year when I focusout and come back to it. If you found the error in the code please let me know.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9twr8se5/1/)

Comment: if you remove the `beforeShow` part then the date won't change when returning to it

Comment: The line `$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));` in beforeShow is what causes this.

Comment: put alert(datestr);alert(year); alert(month); on the proper places and you will see

Answer (score 0):

I find the error thanks for the help @depperm it was in this part

```
month = datestr.substring(0, 2);
```

corrected to

```
month = datestr.substring(3, 5);
```